# I have installed USB drivers but still I can't use my phone

Tags: android

Last week I started android app development, now I have a little app and I would like to download it on my phone ( a "orange tado" also named ZTE kis 3 max). So I watched some tutorials , I enabled USB debugging from my phone, I downloaded USB drivers for zte from here : http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html 
but when I go to device manager it still appears under "other devices" instead of something else ( I saw in those tutorials ) . so when I open android studio , I can't put my app on my phone because it doesn't read my phone . So what did I do wrong , what could I do now ?

Comment: Which version of Android is running your ZTE? Does the debug icon show up in your notification bar? Which OS you are using (Linux, Mac OS, Win 7/8/10?

Comment: my android version is 4.4.2 , yes the debug icon shows up , I am running windows 10

Comment: I've see your print screen. Try to do this: Connect your phone, disable debug, enable and wait for Windows to install the drivers.

Comment: still doesn't work...

Comment: Did you try in other Windows or other PC? Just to make sure is not your PC. Other phone works? Windows normally install the drivers as soon as you connect the phone.

Answer (score 2):

when ever you attach your device(cell phone) to the computer you can see your device in ddms in android studio , if it is not then make sure you have couple of things before going to run the application on device

1. You have adb drivers of the device (device driver ) installed on the pc.
2. if you have first step is ok then make sure you have your device set on MTP. You can make it sure in USB PC Connection settings.
3. Make sure you have Usb Debugging enable.
4. Make sure you have authenticate your device for the computer.
   if not de attach your device , turn off usb debugging , then again turn the  usb debugging on back again , now attach the cell phone to device and wait for a while unless the dialog appears and says to authenticate the device for the pc.

In Your case I think you have installed wrong driver. At least your mobile should have visible in computer with cell name.

I hope you would soon gets its solution .

**edit:**
if you can't find Developer mode -> `Settings` -> `About phone` -> Click 7x on `Build number`(?) and now you can turn usb debugging on

Comment: http://imgur.com/eKKcYd6  here is a photo with device manager . I have usb debugging enabled . my device is set on mtp , I think the problem is adb drivers but I can't find some good drivers for windows 10 ( any driver I found runs only 7 and 8 so when I run it I get an error) . http://i.imgur.com/ynSr1jH.png those are the only drivers I have now . I installed also other drivers but they didn't work like this . can you help me to find some adb drivers for windows 10 for zte ( or mt65xx - my computer reads my phone with this name ) . thanks anyway

Comment: I think your vendor has not made a driver for the windows 10 , please run your environment on the OS which provides  most suitable environment for developers. In my case I support windows 7 as I can found about every thing which I need for development.

Comment: in picture I think it clearly says that your device is not recognized so it is a matter of drivers

Comment: what out most suggestion and tip I can give to you is to use Android air, it facilitates you to install the application with out attaching the device to the computer. It is really good and easy to use. Try installing the Android Air on both side and then run the app and enjoy .

Comment: so I have to install android air on phone and on pc ?

Comment: can you give me some tutorials to see how it works ?

Comment: on my case if you can

Comment: you can see it on youtube dude . I think its a quite proper information you all need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to connect the smartphone directly (not through a hub)
2. Try to install the [universal drivers](http://www.driverscape.com/download/mt65xx-android-phone) for mt65xx

Comment: I have installed the official zte drivers for my phone but looks like something is wrong .. I get http://i.imgur.com/yosrh85.png this error